# Tablesorter setup

Tags: javascript, html-table, tablesorter

I am very new to web page development. I want to create a table using table sorter.
I downloaded table sorter full pack 2.14.5

I have very little knowledge of all this. I wanted to create a table for a game tournament.

I just want to create a table with the following columns for example :

Rank     Name    Team      Wins
  1      abc

2      xyz

3      pqr

4      mno

I want all the columns sortable **except the the Player rank column**. It should be static and not sort on clicking other column headers.

Also, I want a **theme plugin and filter plugin** like shown here :
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-ui-theme.html

Can anyone PLEASE give me a full working zip that **includes all the files including .html file?**
Sorry I am very new to all this.

Comment: Please see: [How do I write a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sharing all the files you needed, you already have them or access to them, [here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2057/). Make sure to include the files listed below, and at least set up tablesorter using the below options.

HTML

```
<!--
  Make sure your table has a <thead> and <tbody>
  Disable sort of first column using "sorter-false"
-->
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorter-false">Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- markup here is up to you -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
/*
  theme   : include "theme.jui.css" & your desired "jquery-ui.css"
  plugin  : include "jquery.min.js" & "jquery.tablesorter.min.js"
  widgets : include "jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"
*/

$(function () {

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'jui',
        headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
        widgets: ['uitheme', 'filter', 'zebra']
    });

});
```

Comment: sorry I m new to this coding. I cant understand where to put files. can you please give me a zip? and where to insert the java script. in html file or in .js files.

Comment: ok. thank you so much. I have one more question. Can we add pages to it? Like if have many more columns. I just want to exclude column1 and column 2 but other columns change when i click page 2, 3 etc

Comment: To disable the sorting, just add a "sorter-false" class to the `<th>`. Then you don't have to worry about counting column numbers. And now it sounds like you want to use the pager plugin - http://www.fileswap.com/dl/V3O77nroHp/.

Comment: thank you for you reply. But I want to apply pager for columns and not for rows. Like there are many more columns wins points etc etc. 40 of them. 1st column is rank. 2nd column is Team name. So I want to do something like. have the 1st columns to show always but on subsquent pages the columns should change. like first page it shows 2 columns as above + 8 columns. second page 2columns above + next 8 columns. 3rd page : 2 columns above + next 8 columns. and so on